# Using LIKE in MySQL without backticks

Tags: mysql, exception, prepared-statement

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 for making an inventory management system. I have a search function which takes a string/sub-string from a textbox and searches the column. I am using LIKE so that sub-strings can be searched as well. Earlier I used PreparedStatement like this:

```
query="SELECT * FROM `desktops` WHERE `Asset Code` like `%?%` ";
```

But the placeholders cannot be put in backticks so I got an exception: *Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)*.

Then I used Statement instead of PreparedStatement and placed the input in the query like this:

`query="SELECT * FROM`desktops`WHERE`Asset Code`like`%"+value+"%`";
//value is the input from the textbox.`

This resulted in the following exception: *Unknown column '%Ru%' in 'where clause'*. Ru is what I typed in the textbox.

Please suggest a solution which will not give me any exception and will return the value when a string/sub-string is searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query must look like

```
query="SELECT * FROM desktops WHERE `Asset Code`  like '%"+value+"%'";
```

You have to use backticks around the column name and singlequote around the value of the like function.

But yourquery has nothing to so with prepared statements.

A prepared statement looks like

```
query="SELECT * FROM desktops WHERE `Asset Code`  like ?";
```

and you have to bind the values later.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) you find an example on how to use prepared stements in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

You have to either put the `%`s inside the parameter for the prepared statement or concatenate them in the query.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE column LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
```